# Change screen on navigation drawer item click

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, navigation-drawer, drawer

I'm new to pure Android, coming from Xamarin.Forms, so really basic question here. I started my project with the navigation drawer template, and I'm trying to change the "hello world" screen that I see by default when I select one of the navigation drawer items. I see there is a relative layout in content_main.xml that defines the "Hello World" screen. How can I switch the screen I see to, say, another xml layout? Something like this

```
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.screen1) {
        // set current screen to content_main.xml
    } else if (id == R.id.screen2) {
        // set current screen to my_new_screen.xml
    } else if (id == R.id.screen3) {
        // set current screen to my_other_new_screen.xml
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either start new Activity on item click like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

or if you are using fragments you can change fragment by this code

```
Fragment newFragment = new YourNewFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_name, newFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
   public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new OneFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new TwoFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new ThreeFragment();
                break;


        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();


        }
    }
```

As you have used navigation drawer you ought to create fragment for each item of the drawer.
So,start with creating fragment and pass it for individual items as above
Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing Navigation Drawer then definitely you will you use fragments. So you can use below code:-

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
   Fragment fragment = null;
    int id = item.getItemId();
    String get_title = item.getTitle().toString();

    if (id == R.id.nav_quick_list) {

        fragment = new CreateQuickList();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_account) {
        fragment = new MyAccount();

    }


    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    title_tv.setText(get_title);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```